# JavaScript regexp match against variable email domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to have a clientside check, if an entered value:

- is a valid email address
- has the right domain name

I came up with following code, but it doesn't work:

```
var userinput = 'dirk@something.com';
var domain = 'somethingelse.com';
domain.replace('.', '\.');
var pattern = new RegExp('/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@' + domain + '$/');
if(!pattern.test(userinput))
{
    alert('not a valid email address, or the wrong domain!');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in two steps. First, use a regex like James recommends to test for a valid(ish) e-mail address. Second, make sure the domain matches the allowed domain as [Siva suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552451/javascript-regexp-match-against-variable-email-domain/9552480#9552480).

```
var userinput = 'dirk@something.com';
var domain = 'somethingelse.com';

var pattern = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i
if(!pattern.test(userinput) || userinput.split('@')[1] != domain)
{
  alert('not a valid email address, or the wrong domain!');
}​
```

You can fiddle with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/D67qA/).

Comment: That's a great solution. Im not fluent enough in JS to come up with this, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function,

```
emailID.split("@")[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `new RegExp()` is either in `/regex here/` or in quotes `"regex here"`, but *not* both.  The slash form generates a regex all by itself without the need for `new RegExp()` at all, so it's usually used only by itself and the quoted string is used with `new RegExp()`.

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@' + domain + '$');
```

Email addresses can be a lot more complicated than you allow for here.  If you really want to allow all possible legal email addresses, you will need something much more involved than this which a Google search will yield many choices.

If all you really need to do is check that the domain matches a particular domain that's a lot easier even without a regex.

```
var userinput = 'dirk@something.com';
var domain = 'somethingelse.com';
var testValue = "@" + domain.toLowerCase();
if (userinput.substr(userinput.length - testValue.length).toLowerCase() != testValue) {
    // Incorrect domain
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would spew out some regex here, but I think the most efficient ways of checking for email and domain are already concocted by people smarter than I.

Check *[How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)* for email validation.

From that, you can limit the regex and check for a valid domain.