# Running an email regex test - .test() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm doing a regex check valid email function and I get a vague error that it's not a function.

These are the answers I referenced:

*[A simple jQuery form validation script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060292/a-simple-jquery-form-validation-script)*

*[Validate email with a regex in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572254/validate-email-with-regex-jquery)*

*[JavaScript regexp match against variable email domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552451/javascript-regexp-match-against-variable-email-domain/9552490#9552490)*

The basic gist of the last two answers is to run a `.test()` running it against the email input. So from the third question I linked:

```
var userinput = 'dirk@something.com';
var domain = 'somethingelse.com';

var pattern = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i
if(!pattern.test(userinput) || userinput.split('@')[1] != domain)
{
  alert('not a valid e-mailadres, or the wrong domain!');
}​
```

I took this seemingly basic premise and ran with it.

My code looks like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/premium/sign-up/" method="POST" id="signupform">

    <div class="field">
        <input class="signup-form-input" type="text" name="name" id="signupform-name" >
        <label class="signup-form-input-label" for="name">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input class="signup-form-input" type="text" name="email" id="signupform-email" >
        <label class="signup-form-input-label" for="email">E-Mail</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input class="signup-form-input" type="password" name="password" id="signupform-password" >
        <label class="signup-form-input-label" for="Password">Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrftoken" value="<%= token %>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" class="signup-form-input" id="signup-next">
    </div>
    <div class="field field--lower-content">
        <input type="checkbox" name="update-opt" id="update-opt-checkbox">
        <label class="update-opt-label" for="update-opt">
            Sign up for updates from SparkNotes
        </label>
        <p>By signing up, you agree to SparkNotes’s <a href="/legal/">Terms of Service</a>
            , and <a href="/legal/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a> </p>
        <p>Already have an account? <a href="/premium/login/">Log in</a> </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#signupform").submit(function(e) {
        var nameField = $("#signupform-name").val();
        var emailField = $("#signupform-email").val();
        var emailCheck = "^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$";
        var passwordField = $("#signupform-pasword").val();

        if (nameField === "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#signupform-name").addClass("form-error");
        }
        if (!emailCheck.test(emailField)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#signupform-email").addClass("form-error");
        }
        if (passwordField === "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#signupform-name").addClass("form-error");
        }
    });
});
```

When I submit the form I get this:

> Uncaught TypeError: "^w+([-+.']w+)*@w+([-.]w+)*.w+([-.]w+)*$".test is
> not a function 
> at HTMLFormElement. (scripts.min.js:1) 
> at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2) 
> at HTMLFormElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Why am I getting this? What am I doing wrong that the linked answers are doing right?

Comment: emailCheck is a string, not a regular expression.

Comment: Then howcome the error doesn't say that? JS is so annoying. It should've said that.

Comment: It says it.... :) How is it supposed to know that the string is a regular expression. It can not guess what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex has to be like `/yourRegex/.test(value)` (without the quotes).